# Navigating to localhost in any browser opens the "Save as" prompt

Tags: php, docker, nginx, laravel-5

I've never experienced this before and honestly don't know where to start. My local setup is a laravel app running on a docker container. The container is running php-fpm and nginx.

Anytime I try to navigate to `localhost` (any uri) the page does not load and I'm shown the "Save as" window with the URI as the "file name". I tried killing the browser and restarting it, rebuilding the container, and restarting my computer. The logs on the container don't show anything when I try to connect. Usually it will log the request information.

I've tried resetting my repo to a state when I know for sure everything was working. I don't recall a change that caused this. I just booted up the container one day and ran into this.

I'll post whatever information is requested. Really don't know where to go from here.

Comment: You have a webserver running on your computer that adds a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header to every response.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar Deleted the repo. Deleted all local images and containers. Rebuilt everything and it's working fine. Do you know what could have randomly caused that?

Comment: Nope, but I'm not really an expert on nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the repo locally, deleted all images and containers on my machine, rebuilt everything and the problem is gone. This is not a clear answer to the problem but maybe it'll help someone that runs into this in the future.